# How to copy data to USB device

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have a file that was made by typing the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/<device> of=memory_file
```

The source file system is EXT4. Now the file 'memory_file' has been saved to a partition that has file format type: EXFAT.

Is it possible and if yes, what is the command I have to type, in order to "burn" the contents of the 'memory_file' to a USB stick, so that the USB stick contains the data of the EXT4 partition?

Comment: Why are you using android tag ?

Comment: because I wanted to do that in Android external sd card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing backwards..

Prob a wise idea to format the USB first though, and couldn't hurt to change it to ext4 as well.

```
sudo fdisk /dev/<device>

sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/<device>
```

Then run this:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/memory_file of=/dev/<device> bs=1M
```